# Multiple if conditions bash

Tags: bash

So I need an if statement with 2 conditions:

```
if [[ $(cat /etc/hosts.deny 2>/dev/null) != *"ALL"* ]]; then
if [[ $(cat /etc/hosts.allow 2>/dev/null) != *"123.123.123.123"* ]]; then
```

If both conditions are correct it should echo an IP in /etc/hosts.allow.
I tried to set both strings in 1 line with && between but that doesn't work for some reason. Is anyone able to point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `cat` for this; just use `grep`:

```
if grep -qvF 'ALL' /etc/hosts.deny && grep -qvF '123.123.123.123' /etc/hosts.allow; then
```

- `-q` suppress the output; you don't care which lines contain the matched pattern, only that `grep`'s exit status is 0 or nonzero.
- `-v` inverts the exit status; `grep` succeeds if the pattern does *not* match.
- `-F` treats the argument as a fixed string, not a regular expression. This saves you from escaping the `.` to match a literal period, and is a bit more efficient.
- `&&` creates a list whose exist status is 0 only if *both* `grep` commands have an exit status of `0`, and further, only runs the second `grep` if the first `grep` succeeds.

Comment: Don't you think `-q` option may be helpful overhere in grep.

Comment: Seems a lot less complicated then mine. 
Why not use `cat` but `grep`?

Comment: For starters, `grep` doesn't need to read the entire file into memory before trying  to find a match.

Comment: `-v` doesn't do what you want here; it inverts the matching line-by-line rather than file-by-file. That is, `grep -qvF '123.123.123.123'` will exit successfully if it finds at least one line in the file that does not contain `123.123.123.123`; you want success if it contains *no* line that *does* match. I think you need to use `! grep -qF ...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you do, use double `[` to insert expression inside and `&&` or `||` as logical operator

```
if [[ $(cat /etc/hosts.deny 2>/dev/null) != *"ALL"* && $(cat /etc/hosts.allow 2>/dev/null) != *"123.123.123.123"* ]] ; then ...
```

Work with bash 4.2, but not all shell.

Edit : be carefull of space between `[`, `if`, `&&`